# Which jQuery mobile version to use for sliding panels?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Which branch of jQuery mobile should I use that includes sliding panels?

I don't think it is included in the 1.2.0 final release?

It is included in the following branches but are these a branch from 1.2.0?

- Branch: slide-panel
- Branch: slide-panel-refactor

Thanks

Asa

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/branches/

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile

Answer (score 0):

Slide panels do not exist in official 1.2 version. Like all new features it could be included in next jQM version but we are not going to know that until there release a 1.3 alpha version.

Until then take a look at this 3rd party slide menu plugin created for jQuery mobile. Unlike official version this one is stable and working:

https://github.com/tegansnyder/JQuery-Mobile-Slide-Menu

And here's an working demo: http://www.tegdesign.com/tegansnyder-JQuery-Mobile-Slide-Menu/

This implementation works just like current beta version of jQM sliding panel.

Comment: I had a look at that plugin but its not as smooth as http://jquerymobile.com/branches/slide-panel-refactor/docs/panels/index.html. It took a bit of effort to minify the js and get all the css together but it's working.